Displaying European accents without Xorg
I'm setting up Arch Linux on a new computer, and I intend to use bspwm as a window manager. I know bspwm runs on Xorg, and there is plenty of information online on how to display region-specific characters within Xorg (e.g. à, é, ü...).
However, I'm curious to know: can I also display these region-specific characters outside of Xorg, before I install it?
I don't have a specific reason to do this. I'm just curious to know if (and how) it's possible.

Note that my question is about displaying special characters, not about typing special characters.

So far, I have tried this: in /etc/locale.gen I un-commented en_US.UTF-8 as a superuser, but also de_DE.UTF-8 and it_IT.UTF-8; then I ran locale-gen (also as a superuser). I then looked at a file that contains an Italian accent (è), but instead of that letter I saw a square.

There are several possible duplicates. This is ones of them: Unreadable lozenge characters in tty1
